# I have written a C code below. I want an explanation on why the output is 34 and not 0 or 42

Tags: c

I would like an explanation on the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
   int x = 042;
   printf("%d",x);
}
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 3):

42 in base 8 (octal) is 34 in base 10 (decimal).

Number literals prefixed with zeroes are interpreted as octal in C.

Change `042` to just `42`.

Answer (score 1):

adding prefix 0 to any number makes it an octal number.
if suppose  x equals 096 then the compiler will show an error because 96 is not a valid octal number.

```
  int x=042;
  printf("%d", x); /* output : 34
  x is in octal representation but %d is used to print for decimal number,
 so 042 change to decimal */

  printf("%o", x); /* output : 42
  %o is used to print in octal representation */
```

Here, following format specifiers are used:

%d - to print value in integer format

%o - to print value in octal format

%x - to print value in hexadecimal format (letters will print in lowercase)

%X - to print value in hexadecimal format (letters will print in uppercase)

Comment: More precisely: `%d` - to print value in *decimal* representation, which for `printf` is the same as `%i`, for *integer* representation. Conversely, `%d` and `%i` differ in `scanf()` where `%d` parses `042` as `42` and `%i` parses `042` as octal for `34`.

Answer (score 0):

In the C language, a number prefixed with a zero is considered to be Octal.

ISO/IEC 9899:2018 para 6.4.4.1 Integer constants applies

So, 042 is Octal = 34 decimal.